# Best practice working with AI models from inside docker containers

Tags: docker, tensorflow2.0

I’m using TensorFlow docker images for the first time. Before I get going with big time investments, I want to make sure I understand where files should be. Should I store, run, create, save all files inside the container and remove what I want to later? Should any files remain on the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the files always outside the container. I recommend you Docker Compose to setup your Docker environment. Here's an example:

```
# Use version 2.3 of Docker Compose to access the GPU with NVIDIA-Docker 
# (it's the only version that supports GPUs
version: '2.3'

services:

  ai_container:
    image: ai_container
    container_name: ai_container
    working_dir: /ai_container/scripts
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # You may want to expose the port 6006 to use Tensorboard
    ports:
      - "6006:6006"
    # Mount your scripts,logs,results and datasets (with read-only)
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/ai_container/scripts
      - ./logs:/ai_container/logs
      - ./results:/ai_container/results
      - /hdd/my_heavy_dataset_folder/:/datasets:ro
    # Depending on the task you may need extra memory
    shm_size: '8gb'
    # This enables the GPU (requires NVIDIA-Docker)
    runtime: nvidia
    # Start Tensorboard to keep the container alive
    command: tensorboard --host 0.0.0.0 --logdir /ai_container/logs
```